# Can I modify the Alfresco custom data list display without modifying share-config-custom.xml?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I was authorized as an Alfresco server admin, but I don't have the root privilege of the server. I am building a custom data list for my group. I was able to build the custom model and deployed "dynamically" by uploading the xml file into the site repository. Now I want to customize the appearance of the data item creating and editing forms. The guide asks me to change share-config-custom.xml and model_lang.properties files in the installation, which requires root privilege. Is there the alternative way to configure the UI only through the web with site admin role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not change the ui for particilar field(in your case it is datalist field) without making changes inside the installation.

Comment: Thanks. I with it can be implemented in the future.